# How to delete invisible symbols python

Tags: python

basically i read file.txt line by line and the problem is that he reads some invisible symbols. To prove that i try to show length of the string and it's is greater by 1 than real is. 

Here is my code:

```
new_words = []
with open("./file.txt") as f:
    new_words = [word.strip() for word in f]
for w in new_words:
     print("word: " +str(w) + "length: " + str(len(w)))
```

And it shows that length is a bigger by 1 that the real length, for example instead of 10 it shows 11.

Comment: Is this file in ASCII format or other?

Comment: BTW, your "words" are actually "lines".

Comment: idk, it's just .txt from internet

Comment: BTW #2: `print([ord(c) for c in w])` might reveal the "bad" character's id.

Comment: `print([ord(c) for c in w])` helped, in each line there is an additional symbol in the end .

Comment: so, what's it's int value?

Comment: it's 10, it adds 10 for each line

Comment: 10 is typically `\r` or `\n` (a newline character). So maybe each one of your "words" (which are actually "lines"), contains a newline character which is not stripped off.

Comment: A copy of the actual file in question would be very helpful. Clearly, guessing what is in it isn't getting very far.

Comment: it works! thank you @goodvibration t.m.adam

Comment: @goodvibration write it as an answer and i will check it as solved

Comment: Write what as answer???

Comment: @goodvibration yep, actually you are right, it was hidden symbol 10. and the answer how to delete it was useful for me too. so you can write it as answer (not comment like now) and I will accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is that there is a hidden symbol. To show it there is a command `print([ord(c) for c in w])`. To delete it please use the command `rstrip()`, but this returns new string so `w = w.rstrip()`.